# Initialize autocomplete with text on primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When i run my form i need to initialize a autocomplete with text and this code is not working for me.
Where is my error point?

The code from my Autocomplete with PrimeFaces.

```
<h:outputLabel 
    for="chamadoDescricao" 
    value="Chamado" />
<p:autoComplete 
    id="chamadoDescricao" 
    value="#{ordemServicoServicosBean.chamado}"
    completeMethod="#{agendamentoBean.autoCompleteChamado}"
    converter="entityConverter" 
    var="auto"
    itemLabel="#{auto.chamado} - #{auto.tituloProblema.trim()}"
    itemValue="#{auto}" 
    size="50" 
    label="Chamado">                                        
    <h:outputText value="#{auto.agendamentoBean.selected.chamado.chamado} #{auto.agendamentoBean.selected.chamado.tituloProblema}"/>
</p:autoComplete>
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: not show on autocomplete the text: <h:outputText value="#{auto.agendamentoBean.selected.chamado.chamado} #{auto.agendamentoBean.selected.chamado.tituloProblema}"/>

Comment: when the form initialize need to initialize text on autocomplete too.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to show that text? The component's value is set through that `ordemServicoServicosBean.chamado` bean property. If you want a value to already be set when the form is rendered, you have to make sure that bean property is filled with the value you want.

Comment: I want to show the text on outputlabel when initialize form.

Comment: I don't know what that means, but the showcase shows many different ways to setup an autocomplete. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml . What you have now, with a h:outputText directly as the body of the autocomplete, is not in one of the examples.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/w3vWj

Comment: I upload picture with where i want to put the information.

Comment: Are you perhaps talking about a watermark? Example: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/watermark.xhtml

Comment: well, i have method return msg to autocomplete, and autocomplete initialize label with non information. I want to put ( TEXT ) on inicialization of label autocomplete.

Comment: I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h:outputLabel                                     
                                   value="Chamado"/>
                            <p:autoComplete                                         
                                    value="#{ordemServicoServicosBean.chamado}"
                                    completeMethod="#{agendamentoBean.autoCompleteChamado}"
                                    converter="entityConverter" 
                                    var="auto"
                                    itemLabel="#{auto.chamado} - #{auto.tituloProblema.trim()}" 
                                    itemValue="#{auto}" 
                                    size="50"                               
                                    id="keyword">
```